# JS: Nested object which will inherit from the main object's prototype

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if it is a good design to have an object with a property which will inherit from the same prototype as the object. Consider the following piece of code:

```
let Sme = {
    e164Addr,
    ton,
    normalise : function(){
        // normalise e164Addr to international
      this.ton = 1;

      return 0;
    }
}

let Sim = Object.create(Sme);
Sim.setIMSI = function(imsi){
   this._imsi = imsi;
}
Sim.getIMSI = function(){
   return this._imsi;
}
Sim.setLocation = function(vlrAddr, ton){
   this._vlr = Object.create(Sme);
   this._vlr.e164Addr = vlrAddr;
   this._vlr.ton = ton;
   this._vlr.normalise();
}
Sim.getLocation = function(){
   return this._vlr;
}

function createSim(msisdn, ton){
   let sim = Object.create(Sim);
   sim.e164Addr = msisdn;
   sim.ton = ton;

   return sim;
}

let sim = createSim('359883123456', 1);
sim.setLocation('359881234567', 1);
```

I'm talking about the sim._vlr property whose __proto__ is Sme (the same as Sim's).

Comment: There's nothing special about it. It's just a coincidence that a `Sim` contains an unrelated `Sme` object.

Comment: I would use the second Object.create param to do `Object.create(sme,{ setIMSI(imsi){...} })`